# Asp.Net Core 3.1 how to setup 3 .net core webapps (sites) under one Identity instance. (Single Sign on) SSO -Roles Span all 3 sites

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identity

In the old .Net  membership  each app could be added and an application id, identified what site the user had access to. And the roles where assigned at a directory/folder level. With core and Identity I’m confused as to how I can get the same SSO affect. I want to assign roles that span all three Apps/sites? 1. Is this possible? And if so How would I go about it.  I have gone over the Identity documentation a number of time, but regarding this scenario can’t seem to get a clear picture.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you read "Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core"? Found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. About the 4th paragraph down Rick talks about profiles in a database--that is where users would be tied to available applications?

Comment: Yes but nothing about SSO and Role management cross the 3 sites.

Comment: I found the Answer Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0  sharing. Hope this helps anyone haveing the same problem.